# mysql error while creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I am new to mysql, please help me to make this table execute.

```
CREATE TABLE `jjsaar`.`dd_chq` (
  `reg_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receipt_no` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `add` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `purpose` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `pay_method` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `amount` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dd_chq_no` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `bank_details` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reg_id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* error when you add questions regarding an error.

Comment: Give varchar limit like varchar(20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have this error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NOT NULL,
>         `add` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>         `phone_no` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,  ' at line 4:

you should specify the length for `VARCHAR` values, eg

```
`name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
```

you working `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE `jjsaar`.`dd_chq` 
(
  `reg_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receipt_no` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `add` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `purpose` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `pay_method` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `amount` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dd_chq_no` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `bank_details` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reg_id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ac0f)

Comment: see [VARCHAR and CHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `varchar` lengths.  E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `jjsaar`.`dd_chq` (
  `reg_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receipt_no` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `add` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `purpose` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `pay_method` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `amount` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dd_chq_no` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `bank_details` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reg_id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: thank u geeks, its executed!!